# Android: How to Play video and show Camera preview in one activity?

Tags: android, video, camera, playback

How to play video and show Camera preview in one activity?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by building a [custom camera application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) which will pipe the camera's preview output into a [`SurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html), and you will also need to have a separate [`VideoView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) in the window in which to play a video.

Make sure to watch out for layering these as `VideoView`s use `SurfaceView`s underneath and multiple `SurfaceView`s do not play well on top of each other.

Comment: It semms the method doesn't work, I create a VideoView which is used to play video, and a Surface used to show camera preview.   When the activity start, the videoview play a movie,and then I start camera and show the preview on the surfaceview, at this time,my videoview show black and crash **

Comment: It sounds like you are on your way, then! I would recommend asking a new, more specific question. For instance, what is the error log upon crash? Etc.

Comment: @DanielSmith Hi, I have both videoview and surfaceview(framelayout) in a viewswitcher. On clicking record button, i need to switch between them. My problem is that, switching of views occurs after recording starts and thus thowing error "Lost surface". Please help.